# java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method android

Tags: android

i am a beginner in the android, and i dont know what is the problem in my code ! and i need your help, this is my code:
i am trying to do a calculator = - / * ..... and i removed the if view==pbtn for example...just to try the onclick function...and i cant find what is my problem

```
package com.michael.mikematta.calculator;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import static com.michael.mikematta.calculator.R.id.FirstNum;
import static com.michael.mikematta.calculator.R.id.HelokBtn;
import static com.michael.mikematta.calculator.R.id.KafolBtn;
import static com.michael.mikematta.calculator.R.id.MinusBtn;
import static com.michael.mikematta.calculator.R.id.PlusBtn;
import static com.michael.mikematta.calculator.R.id.SecondNum;
import static com.michael.mikematta.calculator.R.id.TheResult;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    EditText firstnumx;
    EditText secondnum;
    Button pbtn;
    Button minusbtn;
    Button kafolbtn;
    Button helokbtn;
    TextView theresult;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button pbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.PlusBtn);
        Button minusbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.MinusBtn);
        Button kafolbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.KafolBtn);
        Button helokbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.HelokBtn);
        EditText firstnum = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.FirstNum);
        EditText secondnum = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.SecondNum);
        TextView theresult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TheResult);

        minusbtn.setOnClickListener(this);
        pbtn.setOnClickListener(this);
        kafolbtn.setOnClickListener(this);
        helokbtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {


        theresult.setText("hi");


    }
}
```

my xml:

```
 <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:orientation="vertical"

        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <TextView
            android:text="Hello Calculator"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            />
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="Enter First Num"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:id="@+id/FirstNum"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            />
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="Enter Second Num"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:id="@+id/SecondNum"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="+"
            android:background="#ffeeeeee"
            android:textSize="22dp"
            android:id="@+id/PlusBtn"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="-"
            android:background="#ffeeeeee"
            android:textSize="22dp"
            android:id="@+id/MinusBtn"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="*"
            android:background="#ffeeeeee"
            android:textSize="22dp"
            android:id="@+id/KafolBtn"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="/"
            android:background="#ffeeeeee"
            android:textSize="22dp"
            android:id="@+id/HelokBtn"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            />
        <TextView
            android:text="Here will be your result"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:background="#ffff714f"
            android:id="@+id/TheResult"
            />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Exception:

```
02-08 03:09:50.468    1648-1666/com.michael.mikematta.calcu2 W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
02-08 03:09:50.468    1648-1666/com.michael.mikematta.calcu2 W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xaeeff540, error=EGL_SUCCESS
02-08 03:09:50.538    1648-1648/com.michael.mikematta.calcu2 I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 33 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-08 03:09:51.177    1648-1648/com.michael.mikematta.calcu2 I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 37 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-08 03:09:53.984    1648-1648/com.michael.mikematta.calcu2 D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
02-08 03:09:54.000    1648-1648/com.michael.mikematta.calcu2 E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.michael.mikematta.calcu2, PID: 1648
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
            at com.michael.mikematta.calcu2.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:47)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
02-08 03:09:57.267    1648-1648/com.michael.mikematta.calcu2 I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 1648 SIG: 9
```

any help please?

Comment: What is the problem... ? Explain it properly.

Comment: onclick the app crash @SarveshKumarSingh

Comment: where is the Error log from LogCat... ?

Comment: @MikhaMatta : First, remove all of the lines to `import static...` for the `R.id` entries. Who told you to do that? Second, post your `activity_main.xml` file and also your Logcat stacktrace showing the crash.

Comment: Well I think I got the error.

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh what is the error ? anywhay...will post my xml

Comment: I think... I am wrong about the error. Can you post the logcat error log ?

Comment: ok will post in new answer

Comment: EXCEPTION: main Process: com.michael.mikematta.calcu2, PID: 1648 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference at com.michael.mikematta.calcu2.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:47)

Comment: Are you sure... this xml is named as `activity_main.xml` ..?

Comment: Ok... @Shobhit provided the answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are initializing a local copy of variable `theresult` in `onCreate`:

```
TextView theresult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TheResult);
```

But in `onClick` you are trying to access another instance of the variable `theresult` which is declared outside `onCreate`. This one has not been initialized yet. That's why giving its giving null when you are trying to do `setText`.

To solve, replace the below line:

```
TextView theresult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TheResult);
```

with

```
theresult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TheResult);
```

Comment: @MikhaMatta Try the solution in answer and let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Either check you have initialized the view or may be layout not has been attached to activity.

```
    password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
```

or

```
setContentView(R.layour.login_screen);
```